# Midnight commander surrounds copy pasted text with "0~" and "1~" (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, paste, midnight-commander

This is not reproduced stadily. Sometimes when I'm switching to "subshell mode" with ctrl+o combination and pasting some buffered text either with shift+insert or by "paste" context menu item selection. But it is not reproduced in "panel" mode.

Result example: 0~some text1~

Expected result: some text

Comment: I've found related bug-report https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/1350334

Comment: check this, as a workaround https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196574/106230